# Changing Directory in Python

Tags: python, directory

I have a folder which consists of 50+ other folders. I need os.chdir to check the first folder, take a step back, check folder #2, take a step back, check folder #3 and so on...

My code so far only checks the hard-coded folder but I don't know how to automate it so that it checks each folder in a sequence.

```
facility_types = ["4x Clinic", "4x Hospital", "4x Lab"]


for mnemonic in os.listdir():
    print (mnemonic)
    print (os.listdir(mnemonic))
    individual_facility = os.listdir(mnemonic)

    for facility in facility_types:
        if individual_facility not in os.listdir(mnemonic):
            os.chdir("C:/Users/mf050034/Desktop/test/Client 1")
            os.makedirs(facility)
        else: 
            print ("All Facility Types Already Exits.")
            continue
            for facility in facility_types:
                if individual_facility not in os.listdir(mnemonic):
                    os.chdir(+ 1)
                    os.makedirs(facility)
                else: 
                    print ("All Facility Types Already Exits.")
                    break
```

Comment: I don't have the time/patience to work out a full example right now, but you might find https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk useful.

Comment: What do you mean by "take a step back"? Do you want to keep checking parent folders up to the root of the drive?

Comment: @tdelaney check root --> go to level 1 --> check root --> check level 1. Automating that, I have os.chdir(+ 1), I tried os.chdir("..") neither worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to look at each directory (facility) in the current directory and if it doesn't have an item from facility_types in it, create it as a directory.

```
import os

facility_types = ["4x Clinic", "4x Hospital", "4x Lab"]

for facility in os.listdir():
    for facility_type in facility_types:
        if facility_type not in os.listdir(facility):
            print("Adding Facility Type '{}' to {}".format(
                  facility_type, facility))
            os.makedirs('{}/{}'.format(facility, facility_type))
```